# Plotting power plot in R without using ggplot2()?

Tags: r

Having trouble creating a plot of different power functions for different alpha levels. This is what I have currently but I cannot figure out how to create the multiple lines representing the smooth power function across different alpha levels:

```
d <- data.frame()
for (s in seq(0,.5,.05)) {
  for (n in seq(20,500,by=20)){
    d <- rbind(d,power.t.test(n=n,delta = 11,sig.level=s,sd= 22.9))
  }
}

d$sig.level.factor <-as.factor(d$sig.level)
plot(d$power~d$n, col=d$sig.level.factor)

for i in length(sig.level.factor){
  lines(d$n[d$sig.level.factor==d$sig.level.factor[i]],d$power[d$sig.level.factor==d$sig.level.factor[i]], type="l", lwd=2, col=colors[n])
}


for (i in 1:length(seq(0,.5,.05))){
  lines(d$n[d$sig.level.factor==d$sig.level[i]], d$power, type="l", lwd=2, col=colors[i])
}
for (i in 1:length(d$sig.level.factor)){
  lines(d$n[d$sig.level.factor==i], d$power[d$sig.level.factor==i], type="l", lwd=2, col=colors[i])
}
```

My goal is to create the lines that will show the smooth curves connecting all the points that contain equivalent alpha values across different sample sizes.

Comment: I would try something like `sp <- split(d, d$sig.level.factor);
sapply(seq_along(sp), function(ii) with(sp[[ii]], lines(n, power, col = palette()[ii])))`

Answer (score 0):

Slightly late answer but hope you can still use it. You can create a matrix of results over `n` and significance levels using `sapply` and then plot everything in one go using the super useful function `matplot`:

```
n <- seq(20, 300, by=10)
alphas <- seq(0, .25, .05)
res <- sapply(alphas, function(s) {power.t.test(n=n, delta=11, sig.level=s, sd= 22.9)$power})
matplot(n, res, type="l", xlab="Sample size", ylab="Power")
```

There is one annoying "feature" of `power.t.test` and `power.prop.test` and that is that it is not fully vectorized over all arguments. However, your situation, where the output is the power makes it easier.